# Why do I need to login to Gmail twice?

Tags: google-account

Recently I have found that when I log in to a Gmail account it throws me back into the login page the 1st time but I always lets me in the 2nd time.     Someone is not capturing my passwords are they?

Comment: Which browser? Have you tried with all of your extensions turned off? Have you tried in private/incognito mode? Have you tried a different browser? (Please [edit] your question to include this information.)

Comment: I have been using Firefox.     I tried clearing history (past 4 hours) which seemed to work for a day or two but problem has cropped up again.       Will try disabling browser extensions.

Comment: Problem cropped up after a few days with Firefox extensions disabled.

Comment: Google Chrome OK first try.

Comment: I've also encountered this problem. So have thousands of other students at my college.

Answer (score 1):

Go back to Classic Gmail and the problem goes away. This has been happening since they introduced the new version, tons of people have complained about it and it doesn't appear they've done anything to correct it, yet.